# MySQL compare same values in two column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a data in my database like this :

```
jamu_a | jamu_b | khasiat

A      | B      | Z
A      | B      | X
A      | B      | C
```

And then, I want an output like this :

```
jamu_a | jamu_b | khasiat | total

A      | B      | Z, X, C | 3
```

I'm not expert in MySQL, what kind of query to produce an output like that?
Tell me if MySQL can't do that and need some programming language.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT  jamu_a,
        jamu_b,
        GROUP_CONCAT(khasiat) khasiat,
        COUNT(*) total
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY  jamu_a, jamu_b
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3976/1)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════╗
║ JAMU_A ║ JAMU_B ║ KHASIAT ║ TOTAL ║
╠════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════╣
║ A      ║ B      ║ Z,X,C   ║     3 ║
╚════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════╝
```

if there are repeating values on column `KHASIAT` and you want it to be unique, you can add `DISTINCT` on `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT  jamu_a,
        jamu_b,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT khasiat) khasiat,
        COUNT(*) total
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY  jamu_a, jamu_b
```